# Eclipse doesn't remember my opened files

Tags: eclipse

My problem is quiet simple: whenever I close eclipse and reopen it, it doesn't remember my opened files. It does remember the state of windows and perspective, but not the files. I've been working around this quiet a long time, googling, looking through prefs and stackoverflowing, but no way. Even reinstalling a new version (Ganymede->Helios) the problem persists; I also tried to delete "workbench.xml" and eclipse rebuilt it with same result.

Comment: Could you provide some more details: exact version, distro used (java), entries in workbench.xml (especially the contents of the XML part named editors). Are there any errors in your logfile (found in .metdata)?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
GALILEO
Build id: 20100218-1602.

But is i said, i also tried with HELIOS.

Comment: UBUNTU 10.10 64bit.
java-6-sun-1.6.0.22

But is i said, i also tried with HELIOS.

Editor part in workbench.xml:

`<editors>
<editorArea activeWorkbook="DefaultEditorWorkbook">
<info part="DefaultEditorWorkbook">
<folder appearance="1" expanded="2">
<presentation id="org.eclipse.ui.presentations.WorkbenchPresentationFactory"/>
</folder>
</info>
</editorArea>
</editors>`

Comment: So the editor entries as part of the section `<editors>` are not included here. My example looked like: `<editors><editorArea  activeWorkbook="DefaultEditorWorkbook"><info ...></info></editorArea> <editor id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor" name="MainClass.java" partName="MainClass.java" path=".../ws1/Test/src/MainClass.java" .. workbook="DefaultEditorWorkbook">
<input .../>
<editorState .../>
</editor>`

Answer (score 5):

Look in : Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors and see if the *Close Editors Autommatically* is checked. If it is , uncheck it.

Comment: It is already unchecked, and the rest of checks are checked, including "restore editor state on startup" :S

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, consider using [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/start/), a plugin that comes with Eclipse by default.  It will restore your workbench to the state it was left in for a given task.  It has been a huge productivity booster for me and I could not imagine working on multiple/large projects without it.

Comment: Thank you! it seems to be a nice plugin for my purpose